# pipe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_threads'

Tags: python, pipe, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to run this code for an LDA Topic Model for free form text responses. The path is referencing the raw text from the reviews. When I run this, the error is

TypeError: pipe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_threads'

Any possible solutions? This is my first time running a LDA Topic model from scratch. Let me know if  more info is needed. thanks

CODE:

sw = stopwords.words('english')

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

import time
t0 = time.time()

write_parsed_sentence_corpus(nlppath+'rawtext.txt', nlppath+'parsedtexts.txt', nlp, batch_size=1000, n_threads=2, sw=sw, exclusions = ['-PRON-'])

td = time.time()-t0

print('Took {:.2f} minutes'.format(td/60))

Answer (score 1):

Change `n_threads=2` to `n_process=2` and it should work

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I went back to where i defined it and set n_process=n_threads , and it worked. Thank you for helping me with this.